# Ftp library on c++ with uploading over HTTP proxy

Tags: c++, proxy, ftp

Is anybody knows the free library for uploading over proxy with Http authentication? Maybe some url on samples how it could be.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **[libcurl](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/)**. You can see a FTP upload sample [here](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/php/examples/ftpupload.html).

For adding http proxy authentication, you will need to use options `CURLOPT_PROXY`, `CURLOPT_PROXYPORT`, `CURLOPT_PROXYTYPE`, `CURLOPT_PROXYUSERPWD` and `CURLOPT_PROXYUSERNAME` with `curl_easy_setopt`.

I might be missing something since I can't test it right now, but you can see the documentation in detail [here](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_setopt.html).